# I want a dynamic query to the display the table of data in the each column in ascending and descending order when my mouse click can :

Tags: apex, visualforce-component

I already have the Controller:

```
public class ContactListController {
    public List<Contact> ContactList {
        get {
            String sortExp = 'name';
            String sortDirection = 'ASC';

              if(ContactList == Null){
              ContactList = [SELECT Account.Name, Name, Phone, Email, MailingCity, MailingPostalCode, MailingCountry, MailingState FROM Contact WHERE Account.Name != Null];

              }

        return ContactList;
        }

        set;
    }
}
```

and  my Page is:

```
<apex:page controller="ContactListController">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="List Of Contacts with Accounts">
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!ContactList}" var="contact" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="50%">
                    <apex:column value="{!contact.Account.Name}"/>                  
                    <apex:column value="{!contact.Name}"/>-->
                    <apex:column value="{!contact.Phone}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!contact.Email}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!contact.MailingCity}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!contact.MailingPostalCode}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!contact.MailingState}"/>                   
                </apex:pageBlockTable>               
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

Can any one known that?

Comment: One approach is to do all the work at the client-side using e.g. [DataTables](https://force201.wordpress.com/2013/08/17/client-side-sorting-and-pagination-of-an-apexpageblocktable/), though [sorting](https://force201.wordpress.com/2013/08/23/client-side-sorting-and-pagination-of-an-apexpageblocktable-more-on-sorting/) can take extra work and JavaScript skills are needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can use `jQuery Tablesorter` library to sort the columns.

Code will look like this and it is working perfectly at my developer org.

```
<apex:page controller="ContactListController">
<apex:includeScript value="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"/>
<apex:includeScript value="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.18.3/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"/>
<apex:includeScript value="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.18.3/js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js"/> 
<apex:stylesheet value="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.18.3/css/theme.jui.css"/>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("table").tablesorter({
    theme : 'jui', 
    headerTemplate : '{content} {icon}',
    widgets : ['uitheme', 'zebra'],
    widgetOptions : {
      zebra   : ["even", "odd"],
    }
 });
});
</script>
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="List Of Contacts with Accounts">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!ContactList}" var="contact" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="50%">
                <apex:column value="{!contact.Account.Name}"/>                  
                <apex:column value="{!contact.Name}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!contact.Phone}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!contact.Email}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!contact.MailingCity}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!contact.MailingPostalCode}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!contact.MailingState}"/>                   
            </apex:pageBlockTable>               
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

friends I got the answer now,
Controller class:
public class SortOfContactListController {
    public List ContactListTable {get; set;}
    public String ExpressionOfSort = 'name';
    public String DirectionOfSort = 'ASC';

```
public SortOfContactListController() {
    ContactListTable = new List<Contact>();
}
public String ExpressionSort {
    get {
        return ExpressionOfSort;
    }
    set {
        If(value == ExpressionOfSort) {
            DirectionOfSort = (DirectionOfSort == 'ASC')? 'DESC' : 'ASC';
        }
        else {
            DirectionOfSort = 'ASC';
            ExpressionOfSort = value;
        }
    }

}

public String getDirectionOfSort() {
    If(ExpressionOfSort == Null || ExpressionOfSort == '') {
        return 'DESC';
    }
    else {
        return DirectionOfSort;
    }
}

public void setDirectionOfSort(String value) {
    DirectionOfSort = value;
}

public List<Contact>getContacts() {
    return ContactListTable;
}

public PageReference ViewData() {
    String FullSortExpression = ExpressionOfSort + ' ' + DirectionOfSort;
    system.debug('ExpressionOfSort:::::'+ExpressionOfSort);
    system.debug(DirectionOfSort);

    //String Queryitem = new String();
   String Queryitem = 'SELECT Id, Name, Account.Name, Phone, Email, MailingCity, MailingCountry, MailingPostalCode FROM Contact WHERE Account.Name != Null ORDER BY ' + FullSortExpression + ' Limit 1000';

    ContactListTable = DataBase.query(Queryitem);
    system.debug(ContactListTable);
    return Null;
}
```

}

Visual Page :

```
             <apex:column >
                 <apex:facet name="header">   
                   <apex:commandLink action="{!ViewData}" value="Contact Name{!IF(ExpressionSort=='name',IF(DirectionOfSort == 'ASC', '▼', '▲'),'')}">
                     <apex:param value="name" name="column" assignTo="{!ExpressionSort}" ></apex:param>
                   </apex:commandLink>
                 </apex:facet>
                 <apex:outputLink value="/{!contact.Id}" target="_blank">{!contact.Name}</apex:outputLink>
              </apex:column>

              <apex:column value="{!contact.Account.Name}">
                 <apex:facet name="header">
                   <apex:commandLink action="{!ViewData}" value="Account Name{!IF(ExpressionSort=='Account Name',IF(DirectionOfSort == 'ASC','▼','▲'),'')}">
                     <apex:param value="Account Name" name="column" assignTo="{!ExpressionSort}" ></apex:param>
                   </apex:commandLink>
                 </apex:facet>
              </apex:column>

              <apex:column value="{!contact.Phone}">
                 <apex:facet name="header">
                   <apex:commandLink action="{!ViewData}" value="Phone{!IF(ExpressionSort=='Phone',IF(DirectionOfSort == 'ASC','▼','▲'),'')}">
                     <apex:param value="Phone" name="column" assignTo="{!ExpressionSort}" ></apex:param>
                   </apex:commandLink>
                 </apex:facet>
              </apex:column>

              <apex:column value="{!contact.Email}">
                 <apex:facet name="header">
                   <apex:commandLink action="{!ViewData}" value="Email{!IF(ExpressionSort=='Email',IF(DirectionOfSort == 'ASC','▼','▲'),'')}">
                     <apex:param value="Email" name="column" assignTo="{!ExpressionSort}" ></apex:param>
                   </apex:commandLink>
                 </apex:facet>
              </apex:column>

              <apex:column value="{!contact.MailingCity}">
                 <apex:facet name="header">
                   <apex:commandLink action="{!ViewData}" value="Mailing City{!IF(ExpressionSort=='Mailing City',IF(DirectionOfSort == 'ASC','▼','▲'),'')}">
                     <apex:param value="Mailing City" name="column" assignTo="{!ExpressionSort}" ></apex:param>
                   </apex:commandLink>
                 </apex:facet>
              </apex:column>

              <apex:column value="{!contact.MailingCountry}">
                 <apex:facet name="header">
                   <apex:commandLink action="{!ViewData}" value="Mailing Country{!IF(ExpressionSort=='Mailing Country',IF(DirectionOfSort == 'ASC','▼','▲'),'')}">
                     <apex:param value="Mailing Country" name="column" assignTo="{!ExpressionSort}" ></apex:param>
                   </apex:commandLink>
                 </apex:facet>
              </apex:column>

              <apex:column value="{!contact.MailingPostalCode}">
                 <apex:facet name="header">
                   <apex:commandLink action="{!ViewData}" value="Mailing Postal Code{!IF(ExpressionSort=='Mailing Postal Code',IF(DirectionOfSort == 'ASC','▼','▲'),'')}">
                     <apex:param value="Mailing Postal Code" name="column" assignTo="{!ExpressionSort}" ></apex:param>
                   </apex:commandLink>
                 </apex:facet>
              </apex:column>

        </apex:pageBlockTable>            
    </apex:pageBlock>        
</apex:form>
```

Thanks 
Mohan